# (C, pthreads) Let multiple threads synchronize and continue together

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

I have a program which consists of multiple threads.
These threads have to synchronize at some point, continue together, do their work of different lengths and then synchronize again.

Here's the example of what I mean:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 10

void* thread(void* idp);

int threads_running = 0;
pthread_mutex_t* mutex;
pthread_cond_t* cond;

int main(int args, char **argv)
{
    pthread_mutex_t mutex_var;
    pthread_cond_t cond_var;

    mutex = &mutex_var;
    cond = &cond_var;

    pthread_mutex_init(mutex, NULL); 
    pthread_cond_init(cond, NULL);

    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        printf("Creating Thread %d....\n", i);

        int* id = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *id = i;

        if(0 != pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread, (void *) id))
        {
            perror("Error while creating the threads");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) 
    {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}


void* thread(void* idp)
{   
    int* id = (int*) idp;

    while (1)
    {
        sleep(*id+2); // Thread work

        pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
            threads_running++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
        pthread_cond_broadcast(cond);

        printf("Thread %d WAIT\n", *id);
        fflush(stdout);

        // Let threads synchronize

        pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
            while(threads_running != NUM_THREADS)
            {
                pthread_cond_wait(cond, mutex);
            }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);    

        printf("Thread %d WAKEUP\n", *id);
        fflush(stdout);

        // and continue

        pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
            threads_running--;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
    }
}
```

The thing that happens, is that some (usually #9 and one or two others) reach `Thread %d WAKEUP` but before the others can wake-up `threads_running` is already smaller than `NUM_THREADS`.

How can I synchronize multiple threads, so they continue together?
I am having some trouble wrapping my head around the parallel accesses to variables.

Comment: Maybe you should look at [`pthread_barrier_init()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_barrier_init.html),
[`pthread_barrier_wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_barrier_wait.html),
[`pthread_barrierattr_init()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_barrierattr_init.html),
[`pthread_barrierattr_getpshared()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_barrierattr_getpshared.html).  That might be easier than what you're doing at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for the tipp, I keep it in mind for the next time. Unfortunately I'm limited to the above mentioned functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer seconds later:

1. Change `while(threads_running != NUM_THREADS)` to `while(threads_running != 0 && threads_running != NUM_THREADS)`
2. Change `threads_running--;` to `threads_running = 0;`

Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using pthread_cond_signal() than pthread_cond_broadcast(cond);
So the code flow where while loop is exiting looks like below.

```
        pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
        while(threads_running != 0 && threads_running != NUM_THREADS)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(cond, mutex);
        }
    pthread_cond_signal(cond);
```

So the final code looks like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 10

void* thread(void* idp);

int threads_running = 0;
pthread_mutex_t* mutex;
pthread_cond_t* cond;

int main(int args, char **argv)
{
    pthread_mutex_t mutex_var;
    pthread_cond_t cond_var;

    mutex = &mutex_var;
    cond = &cond_var;

    pthread_mutex_init(mutex, NULL); 
    pthread_cond_init(cond, NULL);

    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        printf("Creating Thread %d....\n", i);

        int* id = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *id = i;

        if(0 != pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread, (void *) id))
        {
            perror("Error while creating the threads");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) 
    {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}


void* thread(void* idp)
{   
    int* id = (int*) idp;

    while (1)
    {
        sleep(*id+2); // Thread work

        pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
            threads_running++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);

        printf("Thread %d WAIT\n", *id);
        fflush(stdout);

        // Let threads synchronize

        pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
            while(threads_running != 0 && threads_running != NUM_THREADS)
            {
                pthread_cond_wait(cond, mutex);
            }
        pthread_cond_signal(cond);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);    

        printf("Thread %d WAKEUP\n", *id);
        fflush(stdout);

        // and continue
        pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
            threads_running = 0;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
    }
}
```